# Prism Xamarin - Data binding not updating

Tags: xamarin.forms, prism

I'am experimenting with Prism and xamarin but it seems I even don't get my property updated and I don't understand why. I navigate to this page with and the title should be updated but instead it is the empty string. Can someone explain why it isn't updating? Thanks!

Xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:prism="http://prismlibrary.com"
             prism:ViewModelLocator.AutowireViewModel="True"
             x:Class="CardGame.Mobile.Views.GamePage">

    <StackLayout Padding="10, 20">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="2*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="2*" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <Label Text="{Binding Title, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                   FontSize="Large"
                   HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                   Grid.Column="0"
                   Grid.Row="0"/>

            <Image Source="AC.png"
                   Grid.Column="0"
                   Grid.Row="1"
                   Scale="0.2"
                   Aspect="AspectFit" />

            <Image Source="AC.png"
                   Grid.Column="0"
                   Grid.Row="2"
                   HorizontalOptions="Fill"
                   VerticalOptions="Fill"/>

        </Grid>
    </StackLayout>

</ContentPage>
```

My MVVM

```
public class GamePageViewModel : BindableBase, INavigationAware
{
    private SingleGameManager _gameManager;
    public string PlayerName { get; set; }

    private string _title;
    public string Title
    {
        get { return _title; }
        set 
        {
            SetProperty(ref _title, value);
            RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public GamePageViewModel()
    {
    }

    public void OnNavigatedFrom(INavigationParameters parameters)
    {
    }

    public void OnNavigatedTo(INavigationParameters parameters)
    {
        PlayerName = parameters.GetValue<string>("PlayerName");

        _gameManager = new SingleGameManager(PlayerName);
        _gameManager.StartRound();
        Title = $"Welcome {PlayerName}! Round {_gameManager.Round}!";
    }
}
```

Like you can see on my property I call the RaisePropertyChanged but it doens't execute I guess?

Comment: Why did you use _RaisePropertyChanged()_ method? The method _SetProperty_ would handle property changing itself.

Comment: Because it didn't  do anything so I tried by raising it by myself. But it can be deleted

Comment: Is the class _GamePageViewModel_ called when you enter this page? If you place a breakpoint in the constructor is it hit?

Comment: Yes first the constructor is being initialized after that the OnNavigatedTo method is called.

Comment: It must be working. For the sake of debugging, try these: set a sample string for _Title_ in constructor, make sure this shows on page: <Label Text="Sample Title">, and also deleting all bin.obj folders because maybe the old code is cached.

Comment: If I set the title in the constructor, then the title is displayed

Comment: I also deleted all bin and obj folders but that didn't solved as well

Comment: Your code looks well and can you please provide us a `Minimal, Reproducible Example` so that I can test on my side?

Comment: @John using Hot Reload feature, when project is running and changing something in XAML (such as inserting a simple space) and then hit the save button, does the label show up?